# After setting up local copy of WP site, homepage works but all other links throw error

Tags: database, wordpress, localhost, mamp

Hope this is an easy one... 8^)

I was provided a complete WP site and DB by a client, and need to see what's in there, so I'm trying to run it using MAMP. I've worked with MAMP successfully before, and done a bit of basic DB manipulation, but I can't figure out what's wrong here.

I put the WP install into a folder called (for our purposes here) "originalsiteurl.com" in my local root folder, alongside other sites I've successfully installed on my Mac with MAMP. Then I imported the database backup into a new DB, edited the wp_options table to change the site and WP URL, and ran a search-and-replace tool to change all references to http://originalsite.com to http://localhost/originalsiteurl.com . Updated wp-config, and... the homepage works!

But when I click on any other link, it returns an error:

**Not Found**
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

So I redid the DB import, this time just changing the two options in wp_options and doing nothing else. Same result - homepage loads fine, all other pages are a no go.

DB stuff can be daunting but I've had previous good luck with making changes and getting things working - so I'm just stumped as to what to do here, or why this specific error is coming up (why is it referring to index.php?)

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check In Database, in table "wp_options"
site_url  and home is updated. if not then you can update it directly

or

with the following query , make sure that you replace example.com with your live site’s URL and http://localhost/mylocalsite with the local server URL of your site.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'https://www.example.com', 'http://localhost/mylocalsite') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
  
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://www.example.com', 'http://localhost/mylocalsite');
  
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'https://www.example.com','http://localhost/mylocalsite');
```

and also reset permalink in admin panel through the following path

```
Reset Permalinks ( Dashboard >> Settings >> Permalinks )
```

Make sure menu path in 'header.php' is not static , otherwise need to change that path too

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was just a matter of going to Settings --> Permalinks and re-saving. Voila!

Should have checked the "suggested answers" as this was mentioned in one of them. Sorry for the duplication.